# pass scope variable to scope method

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I see this most of the time

view:

```
<input ng-model="vm.model">
<button ng-click="vm.method(vm.model)"></button>
```

controller:

```
function Controller() {
    var vm = this;
    this.method = function(parameter) {
       // do things with the model passed as parameter.
       // although it could get accessed directly by vm.model
}
}
```

but this would work too :

```
<input ng-model="vm.model">
<button ng-click="vm.method()"></button>
```

Is it a bad practice, for methods in the controller to access directly variables that are in the same scope without having them passed as parameter ?

Answer (score 1):

It's not bad practice to access the scope variables directly from the method without a parameter.

You can pass them as parameter if the method itself is generic and used by several buttons.

One classic example is when you have multiple combination of source and target listboxes to move item here and there using a same method with source and target parameters.

Comment: It also makes testing somewhat easier

Answer (score 0):

This would actually depend on your design. If you want to create a re-usable method then it is better for you to pass on a parameter instead of directly accessing a scope variable.

This is useful if in your controller you are handling multiple views.

Let's say in your `ModelController` you are performing all CRUD operations. You have a create view, edit view and a list view.

Create View:

```
<input ng-model="vm.model">
<button ng-click="sharedMethod(vm.model)"></button>
```

Edit View:

```
<input ng-model="vm.model">
<button ng-click="sharedMethod(vm.model)"></button>
```

List View:

```
<div ng-repeat="vm in vmList">
    <input ng-model="vm.model">
    <button ng-click="sharedMethod(vm.model)"></button>
<div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Following this principle, you should always call functions explicity with parameters from the template.

Let us take an small example.

```
var vm = this;
this.method = function(parameter) {
  //It's clearer that the function expects parameter.
  if (parameter) { //do something } 
}
```

**Benefits of using with Parameter :**

1. It is testable.Code that is testable is pretty much always more readable and maintainable in the long run.
2. It is agnostic when it comes to the caller. This function can be reused by any number of different controllers/services/etc because it does not depend on the existence of a scope or on the structure of that scope.

The order of execution of `ng-model` and `ng-click` is ambiguous. Instead you should use `ng-change` or a `$watch` on the $scope to ensure that you obtain the correct values of the model variable.

Comment: Nonsense. The order of `ng-model` events and `ng-click` events is clear.